# How to create a pwa app store using basic pwa capabilities

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have created a couple of pwa apps. I want to create a single app store from where a user can install  all these apps. There is an add to home screen feature which let's you install a pwa. Is there any way to create an app store of pwa apps via these feature or using other basic pwa features. I want to support it in iOS as well.

Comment: You could create an app or pwa that just serves as portal between all the other apps. Then people navigate to those apps and can install them from there. I don't think you can install a pwa if you are not on the website of it (especially chrome for android won't let this happen I think).

Comment: So is there any other way of creating it and support in all devices? I want pwa app store to behave just like native app in mobile devices.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to accomplish a native app store-like behaviour for pwas.